# Removing the last column of an HTML table - using preg_replace

Tags: php, dom, preg-replace

in a simple HTML table I would like to remove the last column

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th rowspan="3">I want to remove this</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td rowspan="3">I want to remove this</td>
</tr>
```

I am using this code, but I am still left with the content and the **th** and td **rowspan**

```
$myTable = preg_replace('#</?td rowspan[^>]*>#i', '', $myTable);
echo $myTable
```

Question: how do I remove the last column and it's content ?

Comment: is your HTML example correct ? Do you have closing `</tr>` at the end of each table row ?

Comment: Sorry, It is just a typo, I changed my question text and added the missing /tr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this will do it

```
preg_replace("/<(?:td|th)[^>]*>.*?<\/(?:td|th)>\s+<\/tr>/i", "</tr>", $myTable);
```

assuming you have closing tr tag (`</tr>`) at the end of each row unlike in your example

**Edit:** this will remove any `<td>` or `<th>` elements before closing `</tr>` no matter if they have any attributes

[working example](http://codepad.org/IiTJlarH)

Comment: thanks teneff, I edited the missing /tr , that is just a typo. As to your answer, how td rowspan is coming into play? regardless your code is not doing to job when tested, and you be as kind as to elaborate / fix

Comment: @ShiShi I've just tested it and I've fixed my mistake

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

  // Create a new DOMDocument and load the HTML
  $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
  $dom->loadHTML($html);

  // Create a new XPath query
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

  // Find all elements with a rowspan attribute
  $result = $xpath->query('//*[@rowspan]');

  // Loop the results and remove them from the DOM
  foreach ($result as $cell) {
    $cell->parentNode->removeChild($cell);
  }

  // Save back to a string
  $newhtml = $dom->saveHTML();
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/c8wLrVl0)