# PHP preg replace/delete column from table

Tags: php, html-table, preg-replace

Hell people I would like to replace/delete some columns from html.

First I got the table from TradingView like this

```
$html= file_get_contents('https://www.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-usa/market-movers-gainers/');
                                        
$start = strpos($html,'<table class="table-DR3mi0GH"');
$end =  strpos($html,'</table>',$start);
$data = substr($html,$start,$end-$start);
```

All works fine

Then I replaced some html with this code

```
$data = preg_replace('#<sup class="apply-common-tooltip tickerDescription-hMpTPJiS"(.*?)</sup>#', '', $data);`
```

Now im stuck deleting/replacing some columns inside the table because the all have the same class

you can check here
https://tradingjunkie.space/test.php

The columns I want to delete are :

Market cap

P/E
(TTM)

EPS
(TTM)

Employees

Any ideas how can I do this ?

Comment: Why not use DomDocument?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? [Removing the last column of an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635122/removing-the-last-column-of-an-html-table-using-preg-replace)